# ZF2 Route with Colon Separator

Tags: zend-framework2, rdf, zend-route

I am working with ZF2 and trying to setup Route configuration that uses a colon separator.

For example, the web address could be *www.example.com/namespace:subject* and I want to send it to a specific controller, action with the two variables. I am trying to use a Regex since the colon ":" is a special character for segments. Is there a nice way to do this? Here is my route configuration:

```
'dataReqs' => array(
    'type' => 'regex',    
    'options' => array(
        'regex' => '/(?<namespace>[^:]+).(?<subject>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Data',
            'action'     => 'get',
        ),
        'spec' => '/%namespace%:%subject%',
    ),
),
```

EDIT: I want to use the colon as the prefix:resource format is commonly used in RDF syntax (http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/PR-rdf-sparql-query-20071112/#QSynIRI). For instance, a long uri like http://dbpedia.org/data/Semantic_Web with a @prefix dbp: http://dbpedia.org/resource/ may be referred in a document with dbp:Semantic_Web. So for my Linked Data server I could direct requests and include the prefix (namespace) and the resource name; eg http://myserver.com/dbp:Semantic_Web.  While I am using the segment combinations /namespace/resource for now, it would be nice to handle a route with prefix:resource syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use colon in your route. It isn't good practice, because colon is reserved character(see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2)

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to agree with kormik. Why do you want to specify URL's in that way? What is wrong with the default behavior?

`www.example.com/namespace/subject`

eg:

`www.example.com/somenamespace/10`

or even:

`www.exmple.com/namespace/namespace/subject/subject`

eg

`www.example.com/namespace/somenamespace/subject/10`

you can easily grab these parameters in the controller like so:

```
$ns = $this->params()->fromRoute('namespace',0);
$subject = (int) $this->params->fromRoute('subject',0);
```

You would need to modify the route config also.